# Google Search Result - URL mapping

Tags: asp.net, google-search, url-mapping

Searching from google.com, like www.abc.com

Search Result Rank the pages like

Title.....

Description...

www.abc.com

Title...

Description...

www.abc.com/Aboutus.aspx

Title...

Description...

www.abc.com/contactus.aspx

What I need is, when user click www.abc.com/Aboutus.aspx, it should be redirected to www.abc.com rather www.abc.com/Aboutus.aspx

How can be accomplish this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like an odd requirement to me, and one which isn't in the interest of users. If you have a page with some information on, and the user has searched for that information and found that page, why would you want to serve them a *different* page?

Speaking as a user, that would frustrate me. Why do you want to frustrate potential customers?

The point of search engines is to let people get at the information they want - not to get to company home pages quicker.

If the *user* wants to get to the home page, I'm sure they'll be able to do so very easily from your "about us" page.